# How to create a textarea and sidebar spanning full height in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, grid-layout

I am trying to create a UI in JavaFX which should have two columns and one row. The row should span from top to bottom (100% height) and the columns should be 80% and 20% wide respectively. In the first column, I am creating a textarea, while the second one has a sidebar with multiple buttons.

The problem I am facing is that the textarea is not getting full height. I can change the height in px, but I want to change in percentage. I tried adding RowConstraint, but it does not works. Any idea how should I proceed?

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    primaryStage.setTitle("Particles");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setHgap(10);

    RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
    row1.setPercentHeight(100);

    ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints();
    column1.setPercentWidth(80);
    ColumnConstraints column2 = new ColumnConstraints();
    column2.setPercentWidth(20);

    TextArea environment = new TextArea();  
    grid.add(environment, 0, 0);

    Button start = new Button("START");
    HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
    hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hbBtn.getChildren().add(start);
    grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 0);

    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 725, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

My Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `Vgrow Priority` of the `TextField` as `Always`

```
GridPane.setVgrow(environment, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

In your code :

```
TextArea environment = new TextArea();
grid.add(environment, 0, 0);
GridPane.setVgrow(environment, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

Output:

[image]